# access localhost with smartphone and get no response from the server

Tags: javascript, express, server, client, smartphone

1. website works via localhost on pc
2. access with smartphone to localhost via ip too (I receive html, css and js for client)
3. when I click the button, a "hi" is also added **but function "search()" is not executed**
4. **but when I enter the url http://localhost:3000/users I get the "hi1"**

What do i have to do to make this work?

Client Side

```
const button = document.querySelector("button");

button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    document.getElementById("imageDiv").innerHTML = "Hi";//this work   
    search();//this not work
});

async function search(){
    await fetch("http://localhost:3000/users")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => {
        var image;   
        image = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Object.assign({},response)));
        document.getElementById("imageDiv").innerHTML = response;
    })};
```

Server Side

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require("path"); // window or mac
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
//var word = "";
//const router = express.Router();


// configure CORS to avoid CORS errors
app.use(cors());

// configure body parser so we can read req.body
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(express.static('./client'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile("./index.html");
});


app.get("/users", (req, res) => {  
    datafiles = ["hi1"];
    res.json(datafiles);
    res.status(200);
});


app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

Comment: `localhost` means the same device that's making the request. So if you try to use `localhost` on a phone, it means the phone has to have a webserver.

Comment: i mean this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y_Po6Gj8Gkg&ab_channel=ConorBailey
does that change something?

Comment: And if I enter http://localhost:3000/users it works. Unfortunately, this does not work via the button

Comment: correction to 4. i enter the ip of the pc xxx.xxx:3000 in the url on the smartphone

Comment: It can't work if you enter `localhost:3000` on the phone. As the video says, you need to get the LAN address of the PC, and use that instead of `localhost` when you want to connect to it from another device. And you'll need to use that address in the `fetch()` call.

Comment: i receive the website. However, calling the function "search" does not work when I click on the button

Comment: what is the easiest way to call the above program for free and from different devices (locally)?

Comment: Oh now i know. The ip must also be entered in the search function and not localhost. Now everything works perfectly. Thanks alot